# redirect console output from PI to my PC/laptop

Tags: serial-console

Is it possible to redirect PI console output so that I can view the output on another PC/laptop?

As the PI does not have a serial port, is there an alternative approach I can use that does similar to this step in the [Linux Serial Console howto](http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/Serial/serial-console.html)?

> Optional:  Configure serial port as THE system console

Answer (score 1):

After some more research, I have found that it is possible to redirect console output on the PI using some hardware that connects to the GPIO.

More information is here: http://elinux.org/RPi_Serial_Connection

Answer (score 1):

You could also use this serial Bluetooth module.

http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/a-cheap-bluetooth-serial-port-for-your-raspberry-pi

Comment: that's very nice!!!