# How to start installing Raspbian using serial console?

Tags: serial-console

After finding out that I could [redirect serial console output](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9911/redirect-console-output-from-pi-to-my-pc-laptop/9915#9915), I purchased a USB to Serial TTL PL2303HX (Prolific chipset) from eBay.

Next step was to connect the [serial adapter](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9991/connecting-a-usb-to-serial-ttl-pl2303hx-to-raspberry-pi) to the Pi.

I have downloaded [RPI Installer](http://archive.raspbian.org/installer/rpi_installer_08-19-12.zip) from http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianInstaller, and copied the files onto my FAT formatted SDCard.

I have tried connecting via [Putty](http://elinux.org/RPi_Serial_Connection#Windows_terminal_set-up) but I get a blank terminal screen.

**Question**: What other steps do I need?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the files extracted from the RPI Installer, I had to edit `cmdline.txt` and change this line:

```
console=ttyAMA0,115200 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1
```

to:

```
console=ttyAMA0,115200 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200 console=ttyAMA0,115200
```

After making that change, I could boot up my Pi and the console was showing in the putty session, allowing me to install Raspian.

---

**NOTE**: To connect from windows:

1. open device manager and find the COM port for the prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port (e.g. COM14).
2. open putty
3. select **serial** as the **Connection Type**
4. enter the comm port from windows device manager (e.g. COM14) in the **Serial Line** field
5. set **Speed** to 115200.
6. If you see a blank screen in Putty, press enter and you should see the setup screen.